# Trying to find a book about a fallen guardian angel and his assignment (who got turned into a vampire)

Tags: story-identification, vampire

I'm trying to find a book I read 5-6 years ago about a guardian angel who failed to protect his female assignment who then got turned into a vampire and became the Princess of the Damned.

The now-fallen angel is committed to finding her and saving her by helping her soul pass on to Heaven instead of Hell.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're after "[Eternal](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/4936618-eternal)", the second book in the "[Tantalize](https://www.goodreads.com/series/42155-tantalize)" series by Cynthia Leitich Smith;

> This dark romance is told in alternating chapters from the
>   perspectives of 17-year-old Miranda and her guardian angel, Zachary.
>   **Early in the novel, Zachary falls from grace as punishment for materializing in his full radiance in a failed attempt to save Miranda
>   from being bitten by a vampire.**
>
> The tale resumes a year later with the now-vampire Miranda **a revered
>   princess living among vampire royalty** and feasting regularly on
>   humans. Zachary has sunk into a life of aimless debauchery and is
>   resigned to never regaining his wings".

[image]